swiplserver.prologmqi.PrologError: existence_error(procedure, '/'(wordsn, 2))
For my SWI-Prolog Class, I continuously get the following error with these snippets. Is this a problem with my ProLog instance? I immensely appreciate any help.
wordsn/2 to returns first words of the text. It should take two arguments: and the returned text.
%%CONSULT
%Your code here
wordsnopunc(Wordsa) :-
    File = 'alice.txt',
    open(File, read, Stream),
    string_to_list(InputString, CharList),  % Convert string to list of characters
    replace_punctuation(CharList, ResultCharList),  % Replace punctuation with spaces
    string_to_list(ProcessedString, ResultCharList),  % Convert back to string
    split_string(ProcessedString, " ", "", Words).  % Split into words by spaces
    close(Stream).
Prolog: Warning: /tmp/tmpvqkpw9ac.pl:2:
Prolog: Warning:    Singleton variables: [Stream,InputString]
Prolog: Warning: /tmp/tmpvqkpw9ac.pl:2:
Prolog: Warning:    Redefined static procedure wordsnopunc/1
Prolog: Warning:    Previously defined at /tmp/tmp_fd7iu9n.pl:2
Prolog: Warning: /tmp/tmpvqkpw9ac.pl:9:
Prolog: Warning:    Singleton variables: [Stream]
Prolog: ERROR: /tmp/tmpvqkpw9ac.pl:9:
Prolog: ERROR:    No permission to modify static procedure `close/1'

wordsn(
    5,
    ["The", "Project", "Gutenberg", "eBook", "of"]
).


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/swi_prolog_kernel/kernel.py", line 140, in do_execute
    self._execute(code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/swi_prolog_kernel/kernel.py", line 100, in _execute
    result = self._thread.query(code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/swiplserver/prologmqi.py", line 682, in query
    return self._return_prolog_response()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/swiplserver/prologmqi.py", line 829, in _return_prolog_response
    raise PrologError(jsonResult)
swiplserver.prologmqi.PrologError: existence_error(procedure, '/'(wordsn, 2))


Function listmatch/3 that counts how many words in a list match some pattern. The list is the first argument, the pattern is the second, and the result is the third.
%%CONSULT
%Your code here
listmatch([], _, 0) :- !.

listmatch([H|T], Pattern, Count) :-
   H = Pattern, !,
   listmatch(T, Pattern, TailCount),
   Count is TailCount + 1.
listmatch([_|T], Pattern, Count) :-
   listmatch(T, Pattern, Count).


Prolog: Warning: /tmp/tmpfhvjompl.pl:2:
Prolog: Warning:    Redefined static procedure listmatch/3
Prolog: Warning:    Previously defined at /tmp/tmpa23dptf_.pl:4

wordsn(30,Ws), listmatch(Ws,"a|b",9).


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/swi_prolog_kernel/kernel.py", line 140, in do_execute
    self._execute(code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/swi_prolog_kernel/kernel.py", line 100, in _execute
    result = self._thread.query(code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/swiplserver/prologmqi.py", line 682, in query
    return self._return_prolog_response()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/swiplserver/prologmqi.py", line 829, in _return_prolog_response
    raise PrologError(jsonResult)
swiplserver.prologmqi.PrologError: existence_error(procedure, '/'(wordsn, 2))


What are you doing with these examples? A beginner-friendly way is 1. to save the example to a file called something.pl, 2. start SWI-Prolog from the command line in the same directory as the file, 3. at the prompt ?- type: [something]. and press Enter.
